# How to stop dark mode extensions?

Tags: html, darkmode

My website has it's own dark mode setting, which the user can toggle. It also detects if the OS is in dark mode, and uses that as the default for new users.

An issue cropping-up is I have users who have dark-mode forcing Chrome extensions installed. These chrome extensions ruin the website's dark mode...

I am aware of `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`, but this doesn't help because the website takes care of it's own dark mode rather than using the OS preference as such.

Is there any way to tell dark mode extensions to back off?

Comment: Nope. Extensios have more authority than the page content does. Using `prefers-color-scheme` is today's standard and you should be migrating to that standard.

Comment: You might memorize the mode which should be set by your own dark mode, then observe if the setting has changed by extension and change it back =))

Comment: @Ouroborus any idea if the website uses prefers-color-scheme, the extensions tend to back off on their own?

Comment: They don't. The meta is that extensions have priority over pages. The user chose the extension because site(s) aren't providing the user's desired feature(s), in this case, the desired color scheme. I wouldn't worry about it in a practical sense. The user made a conscious choice. If it interferes with your site's color scheme, that's the user's choice, and it's presumptuous of the site to think it should have the final say.